# Reshaping data from from event log

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table of events and timestamps in the form

| EVENT | ID | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| OPEN | 8480983 | 2021-04-01 01:15:11 |
| CLOSE | 8480983 | 2021-04-01 01:18:51 |
| CLOSE | 6429807 | 2021-04-01 06:32:37 |
| CLOSE | 8506827 | 2021-04-01 06:32:38 |
| OPEN | 8480983 | 2021-04-01 06:35:14 |
| OPEN | 8481121 | 2021-04-01 06:35:18 |
| OPEN | 8351069 | 2021-04-01 06:35:22 |
| EVENT | 8481121 | 2021-04-01 06:35:51 |
| EVENT | 8480983 | 2021-04-01 06:37:43 |
| OPEN | 8505163 | 2021-04-01 06:37:52 |
| OPEN | 8505164 | 2021-04-01 06:38:05 |
| CLOSE | 8480983 | 2021-04-01 06:38:52 |
| OPEN | 8448518 | 2021-04-01 06:40:10 |
| EVENT | 8505163 | 2021-04-01 06:40:27 |
| EVENT | 8505164 | 2021-04-01 06:42:15 |
| OPEN | 8480830 | 2021-04-01 06:42:19 |
| CLOSE | 8480830 | 2021-04-01 06:42:54 |
| CLOSE | 8505163 | 2021-04-01 06:43:00 |

For a given ID there is usually a sequence dispersed in the table of events

- open
- close
- open
- event
- close

E.g.

| EVENT | ID | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| OPEN | 8480983 | 2021-04-01 01:15:11 |
| CLOSE | 8480983 | 2021-04-01 01:18:51 |
| OPEN | 8480983 | 2021-04-01 06:35:14 |
| EVENT | 8480983 | 2021-04-01 06:37:43 |
| CLOSE | 8480983 | 2021-04-01 06:38:52 |

I would like to reshape or reformat this table so that for each ID I have columns for the **last** open, event and close entries. I need to disregard the first open-close pair that do not have an event.

E.g.

| ID | OPEN | EVENT | CLOSE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8480983 | 2021-04-01 06:35:14 | 2021-04-01 06:37:43 | 2021-04-01 06:38:52 |

Can this be done in pandas? Or is it too specific?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df.sort_values('Timestamp').groupby(['ID', 'EVENT'])['Timestamp'].last()\
  .unstack().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
EVENT       ID                CLOSE                EVENT                 OPEN
0      6429807  2021-04-01 06:32:37                  NaN                  NaN
1      8351069                  NaN                  NaN  2021-04-01 06:35:22
2      8448518                  NaN                  NaN  2021-04-01 06:40:10
3      8480830  2021-04-01 06:42:54                  NaN  2021-04-01 06:42:19
4      8480983  2021-04-01 06:38:52  2021-04-01 06:37:43  2021-04-01 06:35:14
5      8481121                  NaN  2021-04-01 06:35:51  2021-04-01 06:35:18
6      8505163  2021-04-01 06:43:00  2021-04-01 06:40:27  2021-04-01 06:37:52
7      8505164                  NaN  2021-04-01 06:42:15  2021-04-01 06:38:05
8      8506827  2021-04-01 06:32:38                  NaN                  NaN
```

Comment: I'm still trying to unpack exactly how this works. I can get the gist of it but don't understand 100%. I don't get how the last timestamp in each group is taken but all the data is still preserved.
If this command was unchained, what would it look like?